# Does react (or maybe es6 in general) allow aliased exports?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

Pretty self explanatory, can I do something like this in react/es6?

`export function BaseContainer() {} as Container;`

I'm programming with a editor on my phone and cant run to test. I also haven't found anything on google regarding this so maybe this can help another on the same path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, you can do it.

Here is the basic example which may help you:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <h1>I'm from app</h1>
  )
}

const App2 = () => {
  return (
    <h1>I'm from app 2</h1>
  )
}

export {
  App as MyApp,
  App2 as MyApp2
}
```

In here, I've allias my component with `MyApp` Name.

#### OR

you can also allias while importing your component.

Here is the basic example code:

```js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <h1>I'm from app</h1>
  )
}

const App2 = () => {
  return (
    <h1>I'm from app 2</h1>
  )
}

export {
  App,
  App2
}
```

and while importing you can do like this:

```js
imoprt {App as MyApp, App2 as MyApp2} from "/path"
```

---

And for default export you do not need to worry about allias, you can export your `component` by any name and import it with any name. Here is the code:

```js
// component.js
const App = () => {
  return (
    <h1>I'm from component</h1>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And in main App you can import this component by any name:

```js
// main.js
import MyComponent from "./component"

const Main = () => {
  return (
    <MyComponent />
  )
}
```

Comment: Ahh ok, thank you i appreciate it! Does this also work for default exports? like `export default /* something */ as AnotherName` ?

Comment: In default export, you can name your `Component` by anything.
I've changed my answer accordingly, please look. And if it help you, accept my answer.

Comment: @Werlious why does it matter what the name of the default export is? You always have to give if a name when importing anyway.

Comment: @PradipDhakal yes this helps a ton, I will definitely accept right after the cooldown! thank you!

Comment: @VLAZ its mostly named imports, I have a class `class BaseController {}` imported from its own file, and i'd like it exposed as `Controller` from a component. Mostly just to have my code look nice

Comment: @VLAZ wait just realized you asked about the default export not the named ones. I was just curious really, might be useful later and is good to have for completeness i guess lol

Comment: @Werlious but the name of the default import *does not matter*. You never have to use it, ever.

Comment: @Werlious I've answer your question for both named export and default export, please look into it.

Comment: @VLAZ ya sorry I responded without fully understanding the question lol. I was just curious, might help someone else so i think id be good to include

Comment: @PradipDhakal Ya I saw it i appreciate it! Im about to accept your answer i just had to wait for the 10 minute cooldown on it